# Font element C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to be able to select a font element based on its style? For example, if some of the font elements have a background-color of yellow, I want to be able to select these elements and be able to jump to them when I click a button. I am using C# win forms application and the html is being shown by a web browser control. Here is a example of a font element:

```
<"font"> style="background-color: light-green" color="black">Hello<"/font">
(ignore the "" around the font tag)
```

Sometimes the HTML gets very big, and I need a way for the user to click a button on the form that takes them to the highlighted words. Ideally I want the user to start from the top of the page, and as the user clicks the button, the browser should shows the user the highlights words until it hits the end of the page. The html is only one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the only method would be to perform an exhaustive search of all elements. However [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) exist for this exact reason

When you write you HTML add a class onto the elements which you would like to be able to select later

```
<div class="select-me" />
<div class="i-wont-be-selected" />
<div class="select-me" />
```

You can then use jQuery to scroll that element into view (though this can of course be done manually).

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".select-me:eq(" + index + ")").offset().top},
    'slow');
```

Now you just need to hook that up to your button and increment the `index` each time the user clicks the button.